# Why UITableViewCell's overlap each other?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I have a simple `UITableViewCell` that contains `UIImageView` and 3 `UILabel`'s. Here, I provide a normal look of the cell to understand the problem deeply:

[image]

As you noticed, the description label can be long, so I set `numberOfLines` to 0. But the problem occurs when that description is empty or small. Cells start to overlap each other. Here is how it looks when the description is empty or small: 
[image]

If you noticed, pictures overlap each other. The constraints I gave to views are the following:

- `UIImageView`: Leading to superview, width and height, center vertically
- BookName(*bold label on top*): top and trailing to superview, leading to `UIImageView`
- AuthorName(*orange label*): top to BookName,trailing to superview, leading to `UIImageView`
- Description(*gray label*): trailing and bottom to superview, top to AuthorName and leading to `UIImageView`(book image)

I also provided `Content Hugging and Compression Resistance Priorities`. I provided them only for `UILabel`'s. I set the smallest for description label in order to it grow and shrink.

**What I've done to solve the problem?**

I realized that if a description is empty, the cell becomes smaller. In other words, labels decide the size of the cell. Also, considering the fact that `UIImageView` only gets centered vertically, I thought that my constraints are incorrect. So, I decided to get rid of *centering vertically the UIImageView*. I set top, leading, width and height constraints only for `UIImageView`. Other constraints were the same as above. But it didn't help, here is the result:

[image]

As you see, `UIImageView` gets out of cell boundary. I thought that it happens because I don't provide bottom constraint for `UIImageView`. But I provide it for description. So, the next try was actually providing that bottom constraint. So, I provided top, left, bottom and width constraints for `UIImageView`. I left other constraints the same. Initially, the result was surprising to me. Here is how cells look when there is no description: 
[image]

Seems like, everything is good(anyway, the image is too small, it tries to fit cell size, that is controlled by labels), but after scrolling `UITableView`, cells are changing their sizes and somehow updates their constraints. Here is what happened:

[image]

I also tried to set `estimatedRowHeight` and automatic dimension, but it didn't help and I don't think that the problem is solved in this way. So, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Set a height constraint for you description label and make it >= to a value that would not make the image clip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep constraints on the Image view as leading to superview, width, height, vertically centered. Keeps constraints on book name and author label as is. Now On the detail label put constraint as top to author label, trailing to superview, leading or left to image view, ***bottom to superview***. For ***bottom to superview constraint on detail label*** change relation to greater than or equal to in Attributes inspector. Change constant to a value you need.I suggest increasing the constant and testing till you get the desired result. Start with something around 20 or 30 and test and then increment value to something else till you get the effect you want. At some value of this constant you will get the effect. 
Hope this helps.

NOTE: This is assuming that your Book name label and the author label at least have some text. It can fail on other devices, so also use size classes to set different constraints

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I will accept your answer, but how you come up with a solution? How you guessed that changing relation and constant will do the trick?

Comment: And, what do you mean by telling "so also use size classes to set different constraints"?

Comment: @abay The detail label was attached to bottom of the cell by your original constraint setting of relation as equal. In that case assume it was 20. So at any time the distance between bottom of the detail label and bottom of the super view will be maintained to be of 20. This can cause image to be out of bounds of the cell. When you say greater than or equal and provide some constant value assume 30, the distance between bottom of detail label and super view will never be less then 30. It wont go below 30 and in turn cell won't get shorter and thus keeping the image within its bounds.

Comment: @abay In short you say my cell should not get shorter then some certain value, when you say, the constraint relation is greater then or equal between detail label bottom and superview bottom.

Comment: @abay visualize that constraint relation was equal and constant value was 20. In this case the distance has to always be 20. Now image needs fixed height. The cell needs to be of minimum height to keep image in its bounds. When your detail label has no text its height is '0'. It pulls the cell's bottom up to maintain the distance of 20 as per the constant. While pulling up, the cell's height might get less then the min height required to keep image in bounds. As a result the image gets out of bounds.

Comment: Size classes is altogether a different concept that cannot be explained here. Please find tutorials explaining this.